# Why do both of my laptop fans run at high speed in sleep mode, but only when connected to a KVM switch? Firmware on both laptops is up to date

Tags: laptop, sleep, fan, kvm-switch

I have two Lenovo laptops connected to one HDMI monitor through a KVM switch. One laptop is a Lenovo X1 Carbon running Debian Linux and the other is a Lenovo Thinkpad T580 running Windows 10. Both computers, and their internal fans, operate normally when not connected to the KVM switch and when awake and connected to the KVM switch.

**However, when I shut down either computer or put either one into sleep, the internal fan starts running at high speed, and it doesn't stop until I either wake up/turn on the computer or unplug the computer. This only happens when the computer is connected to the KVM switch.**

I thought the problem might be that the switch is still drawing power from the laptop USB ports, so I bought a separate power cable for the switch and plugged it into the wall. The problem persists.

**What could be causing this problem? Possibly more importantly, how do I debug this?** It's obviously operating system independent because each laptop is running a different OS, so all I can think of is that it's *something* in the BIOS/firmware, but I don't know how to investigate that.

---

EDIT: For reference, [this is the KVM switch I'm using](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P25XYM1).

**I have also verified that both have laptops have the most up to date BIOS firmware from Lenovo's website.**

Comment: This definitely sounds like a hardware issue.  Look for newer BIOS firmware that might resolve this issue.  Of course, you can always contact Lenovo for support.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old thread but I currently (April 2022) have similar issues, no kvm switch just one single X1 Extreme G3. When I put computer to sleep, it simply did not sleep but had its fans running, just as you described.

You could play around with the bios settings for "Intel Speed Tec", "Thermal Management" and "Sleep Behaviour", all on 1 bios tab. I found following working on my particular machine, to have it silently sleeping without fans:

- if all Intel-Speed and Thermal all are set to "*performance*", then I need sleep-style to be UNIX (though I am running Windows?!).
- if Speed and Thermal are set to "*balanced*", I need sleep style "windows"

After next bios update above settings may vary.

It is a bit annoying one has to investigate how to make a computer sleep. Perhaps this business laptop is meant for 24x7 working :), so no need for sleep.

Comment: Many enterprise environments block Sleep on their systems for many good reasons.